# Bootstrap not loading bootstrap.min.css or custom css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some problems getting bootstrap's css to load. I want to override BS css with my own custom css file (which is in the bootstrap css folder) At first when I would load the page in Firefox i get the error (could not load stylesheet bootstrap.min.css) I changes the order of the BS css links in my HTML file and now I don't get the error anymore, now it just does...nothing. I've looked at the other posts about this question to no avail. I am open to any suggestions. Thanks everyone:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Bootstrap theme link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Bootstrap css link -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">

    <title>Dylan's Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <!--Navbar-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!--Logo-->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
                <!-- Hamburger Buttons for mobile -->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">DD</a>
            </div>
            <!--Menu Items-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End container-->
    </nav>
    <!--End Navbar-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 bg-warning text-center">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <h3>My name is Dylan Davenport.</h3>
                <p>I am an aspiring web developer with a passion for learning.</p>
                <p>I live in Currituck NC. I love nature, music, and all things scientific.</p>
                <p>I am hoping to get the chance to work for a development company</p>
                <p>that has a strong sense of teamwork, respect, and maybe a little fun mixed in!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 bg-success text-center">
            <h4>Placeholder</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JQuery and Javascript Links-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a load error. What exactly is happening that you don't want?

Comment: It's just not applying ANY custom css case that i add. I got it to not display the load error but now I can't figure out why it wont apply my custom.css In my css file as a test I put .body { background- color: black;} and nothing changes.

Comment: Do not use dot before body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to not use the dot for body. You will need to do

```
body {
background: black;
}
```

Using the dot in CSS refers to a class. I also found some other problems. Under your custom CSS linking I have included other css changes I did below.Some of my changes are redundant but some ensure that everything is black. Just remove each one I did and test it out. Keep the ones you like.

This would be your final page and css:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Bootstrap theme link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Bootstrap css link -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
<style>
.row {

background-color: black;
background: black;

}

.bg-warning {

background-color: black;
background: black;

}

.bg-success {

background-color: black;
background: black;

}

.navbar-header {

background-color: black;
background: black;

}
.navbar {

background-color: black;
background: black;

}
.navbar-inverse {

background-color: black;
background: black;

}
body {

background-color: black;
background: black;

}
</style>
    <title>Dylan's Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <!--Navbar-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!--Logo-->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
                <!-- Hamburger Buttons for mobile -->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">DD</a>
            </div>
            <!--Menu Items-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End container-->
    </nav>
    <!--End Navbar-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 bg-warning text-center">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <h3>My name is Dylan Davenport.</h3>
                <p>I am an aspiring web developer with a passion for learning.</p>
                <p>I live in Currituck NC. I love nature, music, and all things scientific.</p>
                <p>I am hoping to get the chance to work for a development company</p>
                <p>that has a strong sense of teamwork, respect, and maybe a little fun mixed in!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 bg-success text-center">
            <h4>Placeholder</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JQuery and Javascript Links-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OK your way works perfectly. However I want to use an external CSS stylesheet. When I copy/paste your code into Sublime Text the page loads correctly. But when I delete the content inside the style tags, and copy it into an external css file, it does nothing. Also other things of note, my custom css file is in my bootstrap css folder, and is named custom.css. Do I need to drag and drop the custom.css file into my project folder? I want to be able to change boostrap's style settings with my own css.

Comment: Here is a picture of the error that occurs:
https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipNXoHY2XI4LBbMtOU6MvSVwPh6_ejyUHf3n0B-g\

Comment: Yes you must have your css file in the project folder.

Comment: @D.Davenport What you need to do, is in the directory where your html file is create another folder called css and then put the custom.css in there. Then don't change your link, it should work.

Comment: Inside your web directory there should be a `index.html` file and a directory called `css`. Inside this directory you should place your `custom.css` file. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Yep. What you suggested worked perfectly. I added the custom.css file into the project folder and linked it in the HTML document using the absolute path l. Now it works like a charm. Thanks Riz for all your help.